# When can Super Troops be unlocked and which can I use if I maxed out the previous TH level?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When can I unlock Super Troops? I see Super Troops attacking my base, and I have super troops portions which I am unable to use.

Answer (score 0):

**REQUIREMENTS:**

> TH11

> The “normal troops” to a specified level such as level 8 for barbarians. It is worth noting that not every super troop will be available to use at TH11, such as giants. You need level 9 giants for super giants, but giants can only be upgraded to level 8 at TH11 (with level 9 labratory)

> 25,000 dark elixir will buy you **3 days** of super troop use, so spend it wisely